# can not start g3log c++

Tags: c++, logging

I'm new in c++ (10 days) but I need to log my project inside the docker. I choose the g3log lib, built it from sources, and tried to create a simple program with logging. Can somebody explain to me why it does not work?
main.cpp:

```
#include <g3log/g3log.hpp>
#include <g3log/logworker.hpp>
#include <memory>

const std::string path_to_log_file = "/tmp/";
const std::string label = "firstlog";

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   using namespace g3;
   auto worker = LogWorker::createLogWorker();
   auto defaultHandler = worker->addDefaultLogger(label,
                                                 path_to_log_file);
   // logger is initialized
   g3::initializeLogging(worker.get());
   LOG(DEBUG) << "Make log call, then add another sink";
   LOG(WARNING) << "This log call, may or may not happend before"
                << "the sinkHandle->call below";

   g3::internal::shutDownLogging();
}
```

code of build finish error:

```
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file <

Starting build...
Build finished with error:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3wZf0C.o: in function `main':/pass/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `g3::LogWorker::createLogWorker()'                                                                                                                                                                                 /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `g3::LogWorker::addDefaultLogger(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
 /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `g3::initializeLogging(g3::LogWorker*)'                                                                                                                                      /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `g3::logLevel(LEVELS)'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `LogCapture::LogCapture(char const*, int, char const*, LEVELS const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
 usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `LogCapture::~LogCapture()'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `g3::logLevel(LEVELS)'
                                                                                                  /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `LogCapture::LogCapture(char const*, int, char const*, LEVELS const&, char const*, int, char const*)'
           /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `LogCapture::~LogCapture()'                                                                                                                       /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `g3::internal::shutDownLogging()'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           /usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `LogCapture::~LogCapture()'
/usr/bin/ld: /pass/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `LogCapture::~LogCapture()'                                                                                                                                                                                     /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3wZf0C.o: in function `std::default_delete<g3::LogWorker>::operator()(g3::LogWorker*) const':
                          /usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:81: undefined reference to `g3::LogWorker::~LogWorker()'                                                                                                                     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

                                                                                                                                                                 The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.

The terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I try to code it in vscode on ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0):

An undefined reference error happens when the linker cannot find the definition of a function. You most likely didn't link your program against the g3log library. The [documentation](https://github.com/KjellKod/g3log#cmake-module) states that you can add the reference in a cmake-based build system using the following command :

```
find_package(g3log CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE g3log)
```

When you invoke cmake, don't forget to tell it where you installed g3log :

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<g3log's install prefix>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this code to tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-L",
                "/usr/local/lib/",
                "-l",
                "g3log",
                "-I",
                "/usr/local/include/g3log/",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

this code to c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include/g3log/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and say this in terminal

```
sudo ln -s /pass/g3log/build/libg3log.so.2.1.2-119 /usr/lib/libg3log.so.2.1.2-119
```

after that magic, all works fine!

Comment: Knowing that you used VSCode would have helped a lot.